# Conformal Mapping: region exterior two to circles with common tangency at a point.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I want to map the region outside two circles: $|z+2|=2$ and $|z-1|=1$ onto something easier to work; Perhaps a strip. Obviously, the two circles have a common tangent at $(0,0)$.

I will be totally honest here, I have no Idea how to proceed or else I would have shown what I have so far.  Regards.

Comment: Have you tried inversion in the unit circle? That is $z\mapsto 1/z$.

Comment: Look at $\frac{1}{z}$ as it maps the two circles into vertical lines and then it's easy to see that the outside is mapped into the strip in between the lines (which are obviously the ones passing through $.5, -.25$)

Comment: @Conrad Thanks, but would you mind explaining your reasoning a little bit?

Comment: Circles get sent to circles/lines under Mobius transforms and sending $0$ to infinity means you need to find the lines your two circles get sent to, so check the other real point on each and for example the points $1+i, -2+2i$ to see that you get the vertical lines mentioned; then see where the centers are sent to see which half planes the inside of each circle goes to.

Comment: @Conrad Sorry, I am still lost here... So are you saying if we put $w=1/z$ we get a domain in s-space with two vertical lines.  But, how do we know what those two vertical lines are? I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: Check the images of $2$ and $-4$ the other real points on the two circles. Check also the images of the centers to see which half planes the interiors go to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region you describe is not simply connected, so there cannot exist a 1-1 holomorphic map of this region onto a strip. (The map discussed in the comments, namely $1/z,$ maps your region 1-1 onto $\{-1/4<\text {Re }z< 1/2\}\setminus \{0\}.$)

Comment: After a good 3 day, it seems like I understand the gist of your answer. So inversion, $\frac{1}{z}, maps any circle going through the origin $(0,0)$ to a straight line and; therefore, since the two circles go through the origin they too get mapped onto straight lines. Similarly, knowing the points on the original domain I can simply plug in and retrieve its image on the line. Also, the point on the circle that lies on the origin gets mapped to $\infty$. Am i correct?

Comment: Hi, I can't really read that.